# Is it possible to inject code into translation unit immediately before compilation

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-c++-2008, visual-c++-2010

I build my C++ code base with MSVC++ 2008 and 2010. Is it even possible to get translation unit, analyze it, insert some code if necessary and then pass on to the compilation process? Original source code should not be affected.

Sure, it should be transparent for a developer who builds a project. Finally, it will only affect object files. Visual studio is very powerful. I guess, there should be some kind of plugin API or hooks to do that. Please, give me a hint.

Comment: 'translation unit' is ambiguous here.  Do you want the to analyze the source file, the preprocessed source, or the resulting object file?

Comment: Are you looking for something that will add information to the same files every build?  Or maybe it adds it to this file once, and another file another time?

Comment: Every build. Code should be injected into translation unit that is passed from preprocessor to compiler. Source files should not be affected.

Comment: Can you dump the preprocessed code analyze it with a regular Code-Analysis tool and then pass it to cl? What is your build mechanism atm?

Comment: I use standard Visual Studio's solution/projects scheme.

Answer (score 0):

I don't *believe* this is possible as you describe it, though I don't know for sure.  It would certainly be non-trivial.  The only similar project that springs to mind is [OpenMP](http://openmp.org/wp/), but I got the impression that Microsoft was the one who implemented their version of it.

I could see a template engine such as [Cheetah](http://www.cheetahtemplate.org/) sufficing though.  You would likely give up your bells and whistles like code completion and intellisense though.

Basically, you would set up the files to use a custom compiler to generate the new code in another file.  The C++ compiler would then compile the generated files.  I don't think it would be elegant or pleasant to use, to be frank.

I've used CMake to do similar things, though I did not target it as a general tool.  I wrote a one off for some content generation.

Maybe if you actually describe some of the specifics of what you want to do we can offer a better solution.